# Is THIS necessary if I want to develop Augmented Reality in Android/Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, geolocation, augmented-reality

A very, very simple question. I am developing an app for Android in Eclipse using the SDK of Android an so on, nothing special. My app is going to be a geo-location type. Like this.

[image]

I'm a newbie in the AR applications. I have seen some SDK's like Wikitude, that help us developing this kind of apps.

The question is: **Is it really necessary to download an alternative SDK for this, or, in theory, I could built it by myself without any extra-download?** (more hard-working and time, i guess).

Thank you people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really necessary to download an alternative SDK for this, or, in theory, I could built it by myself without any extra-download?

Wikitude and similar frameworks were written by programmers. Other programmers could write one as well. Hence, in theory, if you are a programmer, you could write one.

However, since something like Wikitude probably has in excess of a hundred developer-years worth of engineering in it by this point, you may wish to use an existing framework, unless you have a rather long timeframe for developing the app.